# Building VS2008 solution using MSBuild 2010?

Tags: msbuild

Is it possible to build a VS2008 solution (C# and VC++ projects) using the automated MSBuild built into TFS2010? When I niavely just run it, the build fails because the 2008 Solution file needs to be upgraded (and presumably so would the project files). Can I tell MSBuild 2010 to just build the 2008 files?

Comment: did you find a solution??? if so can you share it?

Comment: No, we ended up upgrading everything to 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Does this blog post happen to work out for you?  There are several ways you can get it working but just depends on your particular setup.

http://blogs.msdn.com/madhurig/archive/2009/11/25/building-vs2008-projects-with-tfs-build-2010.aspx